# RTOS : Disabling the task preemption

Tags: task, rtos, preemption

I have one query related to RTOS. We are using Nucleus RTOS. But my query is Generic. Suppose if a task is executing and if it's preemption is disabled, then is the task becoming atomic in nature? What i am asking here is, once the preemption of a task is disabled, can ISR routine interrupts interrupt the task? disabling the preemption of a task means, all other tasks cannot interrupt the particular task that is executing. so, can ISR in this situation can cause the interruption? and by disabling the preemption, is it a meaning of disabling the ISR aslo??

Comment: How are you disabling preemption?  Are you calling a function within the Nucleus RTOS API for that purpose?  What does the description of that function say in the Nucleus RTOS documentation?

Comment: This question is already answered here: http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/November_2009/freertos_documentation_on_portENTER_CRITCAL_3448305.html

Answer (score 1):

Disabling thread preemption does not imply the disabling of interrupt it merely means that rescheduling will not occur.  If however you disable interrupts you will disable both.

The RTOS documentation should be clear on this - consult the documentation for whatever call you are using to lock the scheduler.

Comment: Hello, I am new with Nucleus RTOS, could you please share how can set-up development environment...also if any guideline to start with basic example...thanks

Comment: @Shubh : If you have a question, post a question.  The comments section is not the place for questions or answers.  Moreover question has no relevance to this answer in any case.  I have no experience of Nucleus - the answer is generally applicable to any RTOS.  If you post this question of StackOverflow, I suspect it will be rapidly closed as off-topic.  The vendor's documentation is the place to find this information.